# Pandas Naming Group by aggregated column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to summarize a dataset of top 50 novels sold.
I want to create a table of authors and the numbers of book they have written.
I used the following code:

```
df.Author.value_counts().sort_values(ascending  =  False)
```

how can I name the column that lists the value count for  each author?

Comment: `.reset_index(name='Counts')` or `.to_frame(name='Counts')`. They're a bit different though.

Comment: The `reset_index` will give you your column name

Comment: It did the job(thanks) but why do we use reset_index? isn't it used for resetting index to default? how does it rename a column?

Comment: Because `value_counts()` returns a series with index being the unique values in `df.Author`. If you wish to keep that index, then you want `.to_frame`. If you want the default range index and the unique values as a column, then go for `reset_index`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check below snippet

```
top_50= [x for x in df.Author.value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False).head(50).count()]
```